# How to change maven task order?

Tags: maven, less

I'm trying to use lesscss-mvn this plugin to compile all less into css.

But the thing is, before that I need to copy all the less files from the other folder.

However, it seems in maven ,it's execute less compile first. How can I to change maven task order?

Here is less-css xml:

```
...Clean task, remove all files in target/app1/
... Here is to copy all less files from another folder to ${project.basedir}/target/app1/styles/less

...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/app1/styles/less</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/app1/styles/css</outputDirectory>
        <compress>true</compress>
        <includes>
            <include>main.less</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run this, err message is some error like:

```
C:/project/MyApp/target/app1/styles/less is not existed.
```

I am so sure this is because maven run compile less task first. (Clean all files first, and compile less. There is no files in target/ now. So maven throw an error)

How to make maven run copy task first?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goal cannot be changed, but you can change phase when the goal `compile` is executed:

```
<execution>
   <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
   <goals>
       <goal>compile</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Available phases: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the thing is, I cannot change this build process.Do you know how to change the goal in lesscss plugin?

Comment: Can you show us whole configuration? Phases are described here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html